# Section larger than viewport is not scrollable and jumps back to the top

Tags: jquery-scrollify

I am having a problem with jQuery-scrollify. I have a header section which is a 100vh heigh and works without any problems. The next section is taller than the viewport. It scrolls down to it normally, but it prevents you from scrolling further down to look at the elements in that container. When I use the scrollbar and basically force it to scroll down, it snaps back up to the upper edge of the section.

I have tried changing the setHeights variable but that doesn't help.
The weird part is, that when I resize my window or open the Chrome inspector, it fixes itself. Because of that I tried calling the update method in the afterRender function, but that didn't work. Although it does work when I call the update method from the console. When Scrollify is installed I also get an issue where my footer is in the middle of the section above it. I do think that this issue is a result of the same problem as the scrolling , as that fixes itself when I update scrollify as well.

#### These are my settings:

```
section: ".scroll",
      sectionName: "section-name",
      interstitialSection: ".footer",
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      scrollSpeed: 700,
      offset: 0,
      scrollbars: true,
      target:"html,body",
      standardScrollElements: false,
      setHeights: true,
      overflowScroll: true,
      updateHash: true,
      touchScroll:true,
      before:function() {},
      after:function() {},
      afterResize:function() {},
      afterRender:function() {}
```